# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: react-native, build, eas

I tried to build my react native app with eas build. First build was failed due to react-native-navbar-color. Then I resolved the issue and tried building again.Again, this is the error I am getting while building the app.

```
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
[stderr] > Multiple task action failures occurred:
[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
[stderr]       > Android resource compilation failed
[stderr]         ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
[stderr]             
[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
[stderr]       > Android resource compilation failed
[stderr]         ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
[stderr]             
[stderr]    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
[stderr]       > Android resource compilation failed
[stderr]         ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
[stderr]             
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 5m 40s
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a change in the flutter. run flutter clean then build again.

```
flutter clean
```